# Using an operations table for the group $D_{6}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, dihedral-groups, cayley-table

[image]

With $H = \{ \rho_{0} , \rho_{3} \}$, how would I compute $( \mu_{1} , H)(\mu_{2} , H)$ and $( \mu_{2} , H)(\mu_{1} , H)$?

I'm assuming I'd calculate $( \mu_{1} , \rho_{0} )( \mu_{2} , \rho_{3} )$ and $( \mu_{2} , \rho_{0} )( \mu_{1} , \rho_{3} )$ but I'm not sure how to get an answer. Do I combine them together? For instance $( \mu_{1} , \rho_{0}) = \mu_{1}$ and $(\mu_{2} , \rho_{3}) = \delta_{3}$. So does that mean that $( \mu_{1} , \rho_{0} )( \mu_{2} , \rho_{3} ) = (\mu_{1} , \delta_{3})$?

Comment: By $(\mu_1,H)$ do you mean the coset $\mu_1H$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng, yes...I believe it is a coset

Comment: Then looking at the table I see that $\mu_1\mu_2=\rho_4$ and $\mu_2\mu_1=\rho_2$.

Comment: I suppose that the product $(\mu_1, H) (\mu_2,H)=(\mu_1\mu_2,H)$ ,if we are talking about factor group $D_6/H$ which of course requires $H$ to be normal subgroup of $D_6$

Comment: What other group is $D_{6} / H$ isomorphic to?